# Sticky Fn after Home is simulated programmatically, MacOS

Tags: c, macos, keyboard, simulation, sticky

When I try to simulate keys programmatically on MacOS.
I find some keys causes sticky "Fn".

[image]

The following code results "Fn" + "h".
Can anyone help explain whether it is intended?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>

void simulate_key(CGEventSourceRef source, CGKeyCode key, bool key_down)
{
    CGEventRef event = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, key, key_down);
    CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, event);
    CFRelease(event);
    sleep(1);
}

void print33(void) {
    CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStatePrivate);
    
    printf("simulate #: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    simulate_key(source, kVK_Shift, true);
    simulate_key(source, kVK_ANSI_3, true);
    simulate_key(source, kVK_ANSI_3, false);
    simulate_key(source, kVK_Shift, false);
    
    // sticky Fn, after clicking Home.
    simulate_key(source, kVK_Home, true);
    simulate_key(source, kVK_Home, false);
    
    printf("\nSimulate h after Home.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    
    // Simulate h. The behavior seems Fn + h.
    simulate_key(source, kVK_ANSI_H, true);
    simulate_key(source, kVK_ANSI_H, false);
    
    // So as simulating e and d...
    
    CFRelease(source);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    print33();
    return 0;
}
```

I've also tried to print `CGEventFlags`. It shows `kCGEventFlagMaskSecondaryFn` is set. But I don't know whether it is a side effect. How can I prevent the `Fn` flag to be set when I just simulate a `Home` key.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>

void simulate_key(CGEventSourceRef source, CGKeyCode key, bool key_down)
{
    CGEventRef event = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, key, key_down);
    // CGEventSetFlags(event, 0);
    CGEventFlags flags = CGEventGetFlags(event);
    printf("event flags: %llX\n", (int64_t)flags);
    CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, event);
    CFRelease(event);
    sleep(1);
}

void print33(void) {
    CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStatePrivate);
    
//    printf("simulate #: ");
//    fflush(stdout);
//    simulate_key(source, kVK_Shift, true);
//    simulate_key(source, kVK_ANSI_3, true);
//    simulate_key(source, kVK_ANSI_3, false);
//    simulate_key(source, kVK_Shift, false);
    
    printf("kCGEventFlagMaskAlphaShift: %llX\n", (int64_t)kCGEventFlagMaskAlphaShift);
    printf("kCGEventFlagMaskShift: %llX\n", (int64_t)kCGEventFlagMaskShift);
    printf("kCGEventFlagMaskControl: %llX\n", (int64_t)kCGEventFlagMaskControl);
    printf("kCGEventFlagMaskAlternate: %llX\n", (int64_t)kCGEventFlagMaskAlternate);
    printf("kCGEventFlagMaskCommand: %llX\n", (int64_t)kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);
    printf("kCGEventFlagMaskHelp: %llX\n", (int64_t)kCGEventFlagMaskHelp);
    printf("kCGEventFlagMaskSecondaryFn: %llX\n", (int64_t)kCGEventFlagMaskSecondaryFn);
    printf("kCGEventFlagMaskNumericPad: %llX\n", (int64_t)kCGEventFlagMaskNumericPad);
    printf("kCGEventFlagMaskNonCoalesced: %llX\n", (int64_t)kCGEventFlagMaskNonCoalesced);
    
    // sticky Fn, after clicking Home.
    simulate_key(source, kVK_Home, true);
    simulate_key(source, kVK_Home, false);
    
    printf("\n\nSimulate h after Home.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    
    // simulate_key(source, kVK_Shift, true);
    
    // Simulate h. The behavior seems Fn + h.
    simulate_key(source, kVK_ANSI_H, true);
    simulate_key(source, kVK_ANSI_H, false);
    
    // simulate_key(source, kVK_Shift, false);
    
    // So as simulating e and d...
    
    CFRelease(source);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
//    UInt8 keyboard_type = LMGetKbdType();
//    unsigned int layout_type = KBGetLayoutType(keyboard_type);
//    printf("LMGetKbdType(): %d, KBGetLayoutType(): %d\n", keyboard_type, layout_type);
    
    print33();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. And you went to the right direction during your research (checking if `kCGEventFlagMaskSecondaryFn` flag is set).
So solution is ensure that no flags are set before calling `CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, event);`

Just add one line before `CGEventPost` call:
`CGEventSetFlags(event, 0);` and after this it works as expected.

```
CGEventRef event = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, key, key_down);
CGEventSetFlags(event, 0);
CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, event);
CFRelease(event);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I still don't know why the "fn" flag is set. I'm not sure if `CGEventSetFlags(event, 0);` is a good way.  I've added a workaround like this. https://github.com/fufesou/rdev/blob/2e8221d653f4995c831ad52966e79a514516b1fa/src/macos/simulate.rs#L29C12-L29C12 . To check if the special keys are simulating and unset the flag then.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand this as well. Looks like a bug in macOS.